# git: our team is working on several branches at the same time. how can we update those branches from master?

Tags: git

we work on a project which has master branch, development branch and some feature branchs.
each user working on different branch and we are all merge them into development. in order for other users to get the lastest up from the other branch, is it right for them to merge development into their branch?

example:

```
Development  -> A - somework1
Development  -> B - somework2
Development  -> C - somework3
```

now A has been merged into Development branch

should we merge development branch into B and C so those two will be a ware of somework1 that has been done in A?

thanks

Oak

Answer (score 0):

I do this all the time, it works out for us.

The other option would be to [rebase](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html) your branch onto Development.

Comment: thanks! about  re-basing: isn't that true that re-basing shared branch can mass up it for other users?

Comment: Yes, you definitely don't want to rebase history you've already pushed somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Branch A can be merged directly into B and C; there is no reason to go through the Development branch.  But, if A is already back onto Development, then merging Development back into B and C works as well.